# How to delete stale pods which are in Pending state for more than n hours?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am using the following command to gracefully delete any stale pods in *Pending* state:

`kubectl get pod -n my-namespace | grep Pending | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod -n my-namespace`

However, I would like to add a condition that deletes only those pods who have been in pending state for more than N hours. There is the `AGE` column returned with `get pods` but its time unit varies and I am assuming there is a better way.

Also would appreciate if anyone can mention any best practices around this as I aim to run this command periodically to cleanup the pending Pods.

Comment: `kubectl` has `-o json` as well as `-o go-template={{ range .items }}{{ if (gt .metadata.creationTimestamp ...) }}{{ .metadata.name }}{{"\n"}}{{ end }}{{ end }}` if you want a less awk-y way (the syntax is [here](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview])); I would bet there are timestamp parsing functions in awk, too. Separately, you can save yourself a pipeline step via `awk '/Pending/{print $1}'`)

Comment: @KamalMemon That might be tricky to do. Would a scenario where you combine two conditions: `Pod in Pending state` + `Pod older than X hours` be satisfactory enough for your use case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is difficult to calculate how much time a Pod has spent in a particular Status by using `kubectl` solely and without a help of some 3rd party tools. However, I got a solution that you may find useful.

You can list all Pods that are in `Pending` state **and** are older than X days. For example, the command below will list all `Pending` Pods that are older than 5 days:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Pending --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/[6-9]d|[0-9][0-9]d|[0-9][0-9][0-9]d/) {print $0}'
```

Than you can use the next command to delete these pods:

```
kubectl delete pod $(kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Pending --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp | awk 'match($5,/[6-9]d|[0-9][0-9]d|[0-9][0-9][0-9]d/) {print $0}')
```

The value can and should be adjusted by modifying the `awk` scripting in order to match your use case.